# Bidirectional Map in Lua

Tags: lua

How would you go about making a bidirectional map in Lua?  I am new to Lua, and the only way that I can think of is to put every key-value pair in a table, iterate over each pair to add them (key-value swapped) to the original table.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There are other approaches, like, you could encapsulate two tables (left and right) in a table with metatable, and provide methods to ensure theconsistency of the two. Or jus use one table if u dont need fast lookup on the right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a better way (assuming you can handle key/value conflicts). A slightly better way may be to store swapped values when you add a new values to the table (or update/remove an existing value), but the overall idea is the same.

Comment: When putting both directions into the same table, updating the reversed pair immediately when adding/removing a key/value pair is preferable. If you don't, and then iterate with `pairs` to add the inverse, things will break. (You're adding entries to the table which may trigger a resize, which likely changes the order of entries in the underlying storage – so `next`/`pairs` will do a "drunkard's walk", skipping elements or traversing them several times. You can get some ugly hard-to-find bugs if you forget about that.)